# how to use browsersync proxy with spring boot?

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

when I use browsersync proxy with spring boot ? Although the page can autorefresh, but the static resources like css, js, html cannot be updated immediately.

**So, whether is any idea to solve it ?**

**Thank you !**

**ps: i use IntelliJ IDEA**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in browsersync docs, I have fund the options about serveStatic. This is link: https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-serveStatic

I use the serveStatic, browsersync can reload page after serve static. It can guarantee the static resources like css, js, html can be updated immediately when reloading page.